# Rails onclick => 2 items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following works great for carrying forward data from one page to another:

```
<%= link_to 'New Work Order', new_workorder_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick =>  session[:worequest_id]  %>
```

How would I add a 2nd field?  The following doesn't work:

```
          <%= link_to 'New Work Order', new_workorder_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick =>  session[:worequest_id] = @worequest.id, [:client_id] = @worequest.client_id %>
```

Thanks!

UPDATED

This is the code I'm using in the new work order form.  It picks up the worequest_id field from the session

```
       <% if session[:worequest_id] != nil %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :worequest_id, :value => session[:worequest_id] %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` doesn't really work this way – it's an html attribute used to store JavaScript code to be executed when the element is clicked. While you *can* use it to evaluate Ruby code in the context of a Ruby method call (in this case as part of the options hash given to `link_to`), it doesn't really make sense to do so.

In your first example, it doesn't actually do anything. If you check your rendered html on the page where that link appears, I expect it evaluates to something like `<a href="..." onclick="6">New Work Order</a>`. You can, however, store data in `session` (which is persistent for as long as the user remains logged in), which is why you're seeing this data carrying forward from page to page.

If you're trying to fill in default values for the new workorder, you could pass them as params to the path method:

```
link_to 'New Work Order', 
  new_workorder_path('workorder[worequest_id]' => @worequest.id, 
                     'workorder[client_id]'    => @worequest.client_id),
  :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

In your `workorders#new` action, your model instantiation would need to include the params:

```
def new
  @workorder = Workorder.new(params[:workorder])
end
```

However, this might not be the best way to proceed. If there will always be a client or worequest associated with a workorder, you might want to look into [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: I updated my question.  I'm using the stored worequest_id from the session in my new work order form.  If the user didn't come from the Worequest screen, then the new work order will be blank in worequest_id.  So, I'd like to pass 2 session values instead of 1.

Comment: I tried the lin_to and got undefined method `client_id' for #<Worequest:0x007fb4160ab140>

Comment: If the values you need are in `session`, you don't need to pass them as arguments to `link_to`. I'm not sure I'm clear on what the second session value is, but once you set it like `session[:my_value] = value`, it will be available anywhere in your controllers or views.

Comment: MY FAULT - the code would have worked, but I just realized that the worequest is associated to the client through the contact table.  Sorry